# How to webpack React.js using uglify version

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I would like to webpack my React.js app using uglify version

*webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './_react/index',
    output: {
        path: './dist/public/app',
        filename: 'bundle.min.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: __dirname
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: ['babel-loader'],
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

*Terminal*

```
webpack -p
```

[image]

After previewing on the web browser, I got this error

[image]

Please guide, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jmargolisvt said, you need to set the NODE_ENV.

Try updating your webpack.config.js with the following:

```
plugins: [
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({
     'process.env': {
       'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
     }
   })
],
```

Or in your current config as:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './_react/index',
    output: {
        path: './dist/public/app',
        filename: 'bundle.min.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: __dirname
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: ['babel-loader'],
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    }
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        })
    ],
}
```

Make sure to use `JSON.stringify` to insert a string and not the variable `production`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the NODE_ENV to production.  From the [React site](https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html):

> Note: by default, React will be in development mode. To use React in production mode, set the environment variable NODE_ENV to production (using envify or webpack's DefinePlugin).